# Wireframe plots в питон

Tags: python

Программа рассчитывает коэффициент отражения  многослойной системы в зависимости от толщин слоёв (50 двойных слоёв толщинами d1, d2). Если задать d1, d2 одной цифрой, код работает правильно. Мне нужно построить Wireframe plots, где d1, d2 меняются в некотором диапозоне. Здесь возникает ошибка в 13 строчке ValueError: input must be a square array. Как это можно исправить?

```
from math import pi
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def R(n1, n2, d1, d2, lamda):    
    phy1 = (-2*pi*n1*d1/lamda)
    phy2 = (-2*pi*n2*d2/lamda)
    DPD1 = 0.5*np.array([[2*np.cos(phy1),   2j*np.sin(phy1)/n1],   [n1*2j*np.sin(phy1),  2*np.cos(phy1) ]])
    DPD2 = 0.5*np.array([[2*np.cos(phy2),   2j*np.sin(phy2)/n2],   [n2*2j*np.sin(phy2),  2*np. cos(phy2) ]]) 
    D0 = 0.5 * np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
    DS = np.array([[1, 1], [n1, -n1]]) 
    DPD = np.dot(DPD1, DPD2)
    DPD = np.linalg.matrix_power(DPD, 50) 
    M = np.dot(D0, DPD)
    M = np.dot(M, DS)  
    return(abs(M[1,0]/M[0,0])**2)    

x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = R(0.99910053+0.00183184j,  0.92373900+0.00644652j, X, Y, 13.5)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, antialiased=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем, чтобы решить этот конфликт, заполнял 'руками' двумерный массив Z.

```
from cmath import pi
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def R(n1, n2, d1, d2, lamda):    
    phy1 = (-2*pi*n1*d1/lamda)
    phy2 = (-2*pi*n2*d2/lamda)
    DPD1 = (0.5*np.array([[2*np.cos(phy1),   2j*np.sin(phy1)/n1],   [n1*2j*np.sin(phy1),  2*np.cos(phy1) ]]))  
    DPD2 = (0.5*np.array([[2*np.cos(phy2),   2j*np.sin(phy2)/n2],   [n2*2j*np.sin(phy2),  2*np. cos(phy2) ]]))  
    D0 = 0.5 * np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
    DS = np.array([[1, 1], [n1, -n1]]) 
    DPD = np.dot(DPD1, DPD2)    
    DPD = np.linalg.matrix_power(DPD, 50) 
    M = np.dot(D0, DPD)
    M = np.dot(M, DS)  
    return(abs(M[1,0]/M[0,0])**2) 

d1 = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
d2 = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(d1, d2)
a =[1.0]
a = 100*a
Z = np.array(10*[a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a])



for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        Z[i][j] =  R(0.99910053+0.00183184j,  0.92373900+0.00644652j, d1[j], d2[i], 13.5)   

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```